# Orders page is not showing up data

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, data

There is a Magento project that was working perfectly fine before this morning and it suddenly started giving an error on "Orders" page in Magento admin. Problem is: it shows loading forever and no menu tabs are working after landing on this page.

[image]

Here is the output of the console:

[image]

I have also tried like reindexing but couldn't get that work.

Any suggestions why is it showing like this?

Comment: Have you changed in any JS?

I's showing that "}" is extra in your code

Comment: kindly disable other payment methods except for bank transfer and cod check if error will be solve

Comment: No JS file changed.. have installed an extension [GeoIP](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-geoip/) but tried disabling it as well - didn't work.

Comment: Tried it but not working.. table started showing but data is not loading up.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had amazon payments extension cause me similar problem.

Use composer to remove any unnecessary components.

https://www.integer-net.com/removing-unused-core-modules-from-magento-2-the-right-way/

e.g. 2.2.6 update composer.json

```
      [...]
    },
    "replace": {
        "magento/module-admin-notification": "*",
        "magento/module-dhl": "*",
        "magento/module-fedex": "*",
        "magento/module-marketplace": "*",
        "magento/module-multishipping": "*",
        "magento/module-captcha": "*",
        "magento/module-persistent": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule-configurable": "*",
        "magento/module-authorizenet": "*",
        "magento/module-google-adwords": "*",
        "magento/module-sample-data": "*",
        "magento/module-send-friend": "*",
        "magento/module-swagger": "*",
        "magento/module-swagger-webapi": "*",
        "magento/module-swatches": "*",
        "magento/module-swatches-layered-navigation": "*",
        "magento/module-tax-import-export": "*",
        "magento/module-google-optimizer": "*",
        "magento/module-ups": "*",
        "magento/module-usps": "*",
        "magento/module-braintree": "*",
        "magento/module-signifyd": "*",
        "magento/module-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-customer-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-quote-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-review-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-sales-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-wishlist-analytics": "*",
        "temando/module-shipping-m2": "*",
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension": "*",
        "shopialfb/facebook-module": "*",
        "klarna/module-kp": "*",
        "klarna/module-ordermanagement": "*",
        "klarna/module-core": "*",
        "amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-php": "*",
        "amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module": "*",
        "amzn/login-with-amazon-module": "*",
        "amzn/amazon-pay-module": "*",
        "vertex/module-tax": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        [...]
```

run: `composer install`

version `composer.json`, `composer.lock` in version control if you use it